# Image disappears when internet connection is lost

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I'm displaying an image as a logo in my react native project. It displays fine when I have an internet connection. But if I turn off the internet it disappears.

Can anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
renderLogo = () => {
        if(this.props.logoImage.logoImage !== null){
            return <Image style={{resizeMode: 'contain', height: 40, width: 130}} source={{uri: this.props.logoImage.logoImage.ImageVirtualPath}} />
        }
        return <Text />
    }
```

url = "https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/react_thumb_install.png"

Comment: You're loading the image from a website. When the connection goes off you can't reach the website, so the image doesn't show. Try downloading the image and load it from your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can `cache` the `image` if you want to express the same `image` offline.

But it only works in `iOS`. And it has to be loaded once.

```js
<Image style={{resizeMode: 'contain', height: 40, width: 130}}

 source={{uri: this.props.logoImage.logoImage.ImageVirtualPath, cache: 'only-if-cached'}} />
```

If you want to run on any device, you can install and use the module.

You can install [`React-native-cached-image`](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image)

**Example**

```js
import { CachedImage } from 'react-native-cached-image';
...
<CachedImage 
  style={{
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  }}
  source={{ uri: item.urls.raw }}
/>
```

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' mark and arrow for my answer?